# Store variable from controller in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to store a variable created in my controller directly in my database. My controller creates some pictures, generates random URLs, and I want to store each URL in my database. My controller is `Pages` and my model is `video`. In my db, the URL is named `url_rand`.

I tried:

```
url = SecureRandom.hex
@vid = Video.new
@vid.url_rand = url
@vid.save!
```

What is a way to write this with good syntax?

SOLVE:

Thanks everyone, the syntaxe was good, just i delete, then re-create my model.

Comment: Does it work or not?

Comment: The code you have there will set a value for a field in a new record and then save the record to the database.  The syntax is fine.  However, in the wider context of what you actually want to do then it's hard to give any useful commentary.

Comment: undefined method `url_rand=' for #<Video:0x007f8328961038>

Comment: Well then, the error must mean there's no field `url_rand` in the DB. Add one.

Comment: Create a migration to add the `url_rand` field to the `videos` table or fix the existing migration for the `videos` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url = SecureRandom.hex

@vid = Video.create(:url_rand=>url)